# How can I implement this jquery function in angular?

Tags: jquery, angular

I want to use a function that I found to achieve a functionality in a component.

I tried adding it in my index.html. This is my index.html:

```
<! doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title> Test </title>
  <base href = "/">
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <link rel = "icon" type = "image / x-icon" href = "favicon.ico">
  <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel = "stylesheet">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity = "sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt + Y8vinAf7" anonymousorfUU "
  <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel = "stylesheet">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script>
    $ .fn.fitInText = function () {
      this.each (function () {

        let textbox = $ (this);
        let textboxNode = this;

        let mutationCallback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
          if (observer) {
            observer.disconnect ();
          }
          textbox.css ('font-size', 0);
          let desiredHeight = textbox.css ('height');
          for (i = 12; i <50; i ++) {
            textbox.css ('font-size', i);
            if (textbox.css ('height')> desiredHeight) {
              textbox.css ('font-size', i - 1);
              break;
            }
          }

          var config = {
            attributes: true,
            childList: true,
            subtree: true,
            characterData: true
          };
          let newobserver = new MutationObserver (mutationCallback);
          newobserver.observe (textboxNode, config);

        };

        mutationCallback ();

      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body class = "mat-typography">
  <app-root> </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the component where I want to use the function:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input} from '@ angular / core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@ angular / material / dialog';
import {ModalComponent} from '../../../modal/modal.component';
import {ServiceUser} from '../../../../../services/usuarios.service'
import {UploadImagesService} from '../../../../../services/upload-images.service';
// import {Images} from '../../../../../interfaces/images/images';
import {Text} from '../../../../../interfaces/text/text';
// import {Texts} from '../../../../../interfaces/texts/texts';
declare const $: any;


@Component ({
  selector: 'app-pag7',
  templateUrl: './pag7.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pag7.component.css']
})
export class Pag7Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

@Input () formData: any;
@Input () pageNum: number;
@Input () typeOfPdf: number;

@Input () disabledClick: boolean;
// @Input () imagesPag2: Images;
@Input () images1: any;
@Input () texts: any;

  @ViewChild ("fileInput1") el1: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild ("fileInput2") el2: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild ("fileInput3") el3: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild ("fileInput4") el4: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild ("fileInput5") el5: ElementRef;

  currentPageImages: any;
  currentPageTexts: any;
  form: any = '';
  disabledCl: any = null;
  textUser: string = 'ZZZZZZZZ'
  // data = {} as Text
  
  constructor (public dialog: MatDialog, private userService: UserService, private uploadImgService: UploadImagesService) {
  //console.log('Showing Images in constructor: ', this.imagesPag2);
  this.currentPageImages = this.uploadImgService.setImages (this.pageNum, this.typeOfPdf, this.images1);
  }

  

  ngOnInit () {
  // console.log ('Showing Images in onInit:', this.imagesPag2);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit () {
$ ('. text'). fitInText ();
  }
  
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
```

component template:

```
  <div class = "text" contenteditable = true>
    TEST
  </div>
```

This is the error it shows me:

[image]

I have [the same code in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kcevk9?file=src%2Findex.html), if you see it is exactly the same code that I have in my local and in stackblitz

Comment: I think you need to reconsider using `JQuery` in `Angular`

Comment: I understand that it is not highly recommended, but honestly I do not have much time and I do not understand that function much to transfer it to typescript unfortunately since I am still a newbie.

Comment: @OwenKelvin any idea how i could achieve that functionality in angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Directive`](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) to achieve this

Below is sample, the calculations can be adjusted according to your preference otherwise it achieves this functionality

**fit-in-text.directive.ts**

```typescript
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  Input
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appFitInText]"
})
export class FitInTextDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  maxTextFont = 50;
  minTextFont = 12;
  @Input("appFitInText") option = {
    height: "250px",
    width: "100%"
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.height = this.option.height;
    this.el.nativeElement.style.width = this.option.width;
    this.el.nativeElement.style.fontSize = this.maxTextFont + "px";
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  @HostListener("keyup")
  fitInText() {
    const newLines =
      (this.el.nativeElement.value.match(/\n/g) || "").length + 1;
    const textFont = Math.max(this.minTextFont, this.maxTextFont * 2 / newLines);
    this.el.nativeElement.style.fontSize = Math.min(this.maxTextFont, textFont)+ "px";
    console.log(Math.min(this.maxTextFont, textFont)+ "px")
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<textarea
 [appFitInText]='{height: "250px", width: "100%"}'
></textarea>
```

[See this sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5b8wz6?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffit-in-text.directive.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the time but in essence what I try to do is that the text decreases its size (instead of activating the scroll) and if the user deletes a part of the text then said text returns to its original size, as in the example from stackblitz that I placed.